# Devise, Discourse & Single Sign On / SSO , payload dropped, can't sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on, discourse

I installed SSO for Discourse following the official implementation instructions ([here](https://meta.discourse.org/t/official-single-sign-on-for-discourse/13045)) and this answer on Stackoverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478510/incorporating-discourse-sso-with-existing-rails-site-with-devise)).  However, it's not working.  The SSO payload is dropped between the Get users/sign_in and Post users/sign_in actions.

Here's the Heroku log:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in?sso=PAYLOAD & SIG [GET]
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML [NEW ACTION]
Parameters: {"sso"=> etc. [SSO PAYLOAD PRESENT]
- rendering html -
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_in?sso= [PAYLOAD PRESENT]
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML [CREATE ACTION]
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=> etc [NO SSO PAYLOAD,
  Google Recaptcha added]
Started GET "/"
Started POST "/users/sign_in"
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
- rendering html -
heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_in"  host=our_site.com
```

Here is the Discourse SSO Controller per the official instructions (above):

```
class DiscourseSsoController < ApplicationController

  def sso
    secret = "SECRET STRING"
    sso = SingleSignOn.parse(request.query_string, secret)
    sso.email = current_user.email # from devise
    sso.name = current_user.name # this is a custom method on the User class
    sso.username = current_user.email # from devise
    sso.external_id = current_user.id # from devise
    sso.sso_secret = secret

    redirect_to sso.to_url("http://DISCOURSE_sub-domain_of.OUR_SITE.com/
      session/sso_login")
  end

end
```

I customized the Devise views and installed the Devise sessions controller with scope users (class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController).

Looking at the Devise Sessions Controller [source code on Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb), the Get / New and Post / Create methods are:

## GET /resource/sign_in

```
def new
  self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
  clean_up_passwords(resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
end
```

## POST /resource/sign_in

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

The first line of the Create method references the last line of the New method via `auth_options` (which is `protected`):

```
def auth_options
  { scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#new" }
end
```

The last line of the New method (I believe) creates the params that are posted. They're the `serialize_options(resource)`, another `protected` method:

```
def serialize_options(resource)
  methods = resource_class.authentication_keys.dup
  methods = methods.keys if methods.is_a?(Hash)
  methods << :password if resource.respond_to?(:password)
    { methods: methods, only: [:password] }
end
```

The SSO payload isn't being passed as a `serialize_options`.

Here's what appears to be a similar issue devise and oauth [OmniAuth Single Sign On with Devise, invalid_credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205927/omniauth-single-sign-on-with-devise-invalid-credentials) resolved by scraping the token.

Any guidance or thoughts are appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @D-Nice  I frankly don't recall.  My vague recollection is that a Discourse employee resolved it for me.  They are - or were five years ago - very helpful.

Comment: Fwiw, I was able to resolve the issue I was having. My problem was that I had set the discourse connect URL to my domain endpoint without a www, but my webserver was redirecting to www and dropping the query parameters. Adding the www to my Discourse connect URL fixed it for me.